# text sizes different Android phones

Tags: android, android-layout

Since I have a Nexus 5, I'm seeing strange stuff regarding text sizes.

An example: I am creating listview items. I put a bigger text at 22sp, a smaller one at 17sp.

On my HTC One X it looks like this:

[image]

So I think "ok, that's nice!"

Then I run it on my Nexus 5:

[image]

I do not understand why this is happening? Shouldn't the 'sp' part make sure it will look ok
**with the default values**? I am not talking about the user increasing the font sizes in the settings, I've left everything to defaults.

Eventhough, if I would (don't hit me) use DP here to disable the font size changes for text, it will give the same result (not tested, but I am fairly certain this is the case from other tests).

What is the problem here? Is it the newer Android version, or is it the 1080p screen vs the 720p ?

Should I use different values for different DP using 'values' folder?

here is de layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/arrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/arrow"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/address"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="17sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, the default size for same SP value may vary depending on device, just to match its readability designed for the device.

The problem you got is because you have some elements sized to fixed size, post your XML code you use for the row and we can make a deep analyse.

Edit -- After xml

Well, instead of point you the wrongs, I did prefer to rebuild your layout, take a look:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/arrow"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/arrow"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Your layout was too complex to a simple row... now the layout will be as tall as the TextViews needs it to be, and it is not a problem, as the user is already used with his text size.

Comment: added the layout. I expect the 'margin' to be the cause

Comment: I actually tried to avoid relative layouts, because I thought those would 'cost more' than using linear layouts

Comment: LinearLayouts are fast if you don't use weight, otherwise it got quite expensive.

Comment: thanks! Appreciate your help. So using weight => consider relative layout is your advice (going to test your layout now)

Comment: It is not completely the way I would want it to be (NetworkImageView is not showing anything, only when I set the width to a specific value, and I need some margins somewhere) but I'll try to get it the way it needs to be with a relative view...you removed all the margins which I think was part of the problem...I have a design from a customer I need to copy

Comment: I could not reproduce NetworkImageView, but I can't see why it would not show... I removed the margins to make it simple, but they are not the problem, you can put it without problem.

Comment: If you add some information about what the problem was in my layout, I will mark it as accepted

Comment: The problem of cutting letter is cause by the main layout android:layout_height which is fixed in 80dp, but this is not the only problem...

Answer (score 0):

you have to Create two different layout folder and see the result

Comment: Not really necessary if you create a truly re-sizable layout and even if you want to specify by dimension, I would suggest you to use specified styles instead of layouts.